# Is conducting research in the field of evolutionary computing/genetic algorithms considered inferior within the CS community?

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, research-undergraduate

I read somewhere online, how one shouldn't show their interest in genetic algorithms to a potential grad school, as its not the 'in' thing in todays CS community, compared to Machine Learning algorithms. I am interested in genetic algorithms and reading such a notion left me a little bothered, honestly.

Comment: keyword for you is Big Data analysis aka. bioinformatic, yes you right, Machine Learning is better for CS, and today market

Comment: Is your interest focused on developing new genetic algorithms, or would applications of genetic algorithms also be of interest for you? As for applications, there is a vibrant community that applies optimization algorithms to software problems. [Search-based software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search-based_software_engineering) would be the keyword here.

Comment: I would like to keep away from really specific and focus interests. Primarily because I am just not sure so early being in undergraduate program. But yes I do like applying genetic algorithm to a particular problem.

Comment: @nocturnal_study OK, maybe search-based software engineering could be for you. When tailoring your application documents to a specific grad school, you may check the websites of their software engineering department/work groups and see if they are working on problems that could benefit from the application of genetic algorithms. Be sure to mention these applications in your application documents.

Comment: @lighthouse keep I will remember to check that out.

Comment: When you say "genetic algorithms" do you mean: algorithms for genetics, or do you mean the nondifferentiable optimization technique? If you mean the second, then it really depends on the ML program. A statistical ML program will likely not respect that due to the nondifferentiable aspect.

Comment: @Andnp I meant optimization techniques for NP hard problems.

Comment: Evolutionary computing is mostly useless for building solutions to problems in AI in industry. If you want to be an academician who publishes 1000 papers which only other academicians and their students would cite, go ahead and take it up. Otherwise, this area of work is not the best use of energy. Transactions on Evolutionary Computation is filled with experimental work with no serious comparison with the state-of-the-art. IF you take up this field you will be doing mediocre work for the rest of your life.

Answer (score 7):

When applying to a school you should be aware of the faculty at that school and the research they perform. Take a look at their research papers. If nobody at the school does work in genetic algorithms, then it probably isn't going to help you to mention your interest in the area.

If you have a sincere interest in genetic algorithms, then you need to find a school with researchers that are doing work in that area. If there is a prominent researcher at a school working on genetic algorithms, then you really want to mention your interest. If the researcher is accepting new students it might improve your chances of acceptance.

There are always hot areas in a field, and machine learning is currently hot, and genetic algorithms aren't as hot. But, there is good work being done in both fields. (There is also bad work being done in both fields.) I would advise you to find someone doing excellent work, and then the field that you are in will not matter as much.

Comment: This is vastly more important than what is hot or trendy. If you aren't interested in what the faculty at the school are working on, it's not just a bad sign for you getting into the school, but also a sign you wouldn't be happy there.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I just am not too sure about my specific interests in research so early. My research has been in genetic algorithms, so I have to talk about that in my SOP as that is all I have as of now. My concern is primarily because of this...So to paraphrase I haven't taken up this particular topic just because I absolutely love that more than anything else, it just happened to be one of the initial choice. On a sidenote, I did enjoy working on it though.

Comment: @nocturnal_study - I think you are right to not limit what you are going to be interested in. If, when you do your application, you just explain *why* you have liked your genetic algorithm research so far, and make a convincing case that it taught you a lot which could be applied further, that sounds like a strong rationale to join a number of different sorts of research groups.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest having a quick look into combining genetic algorithms and neural networks, some work has been done in this area, perhaps there is more to do. The trend seems to be combining different machine learning techniques (e.g., deep reinforcement learning) and this is something the original poster could exploit to have their cake (research GAs) and eat it (submit to machine-learning conferences where neural nets are hot).

The question distinguishes between genetic algorithms and Machine Learning. Yet, a quick search on genetic algorithms and machine learning shows that the former may be (and often is) considered a sub-discipline of the latter. Given that the two have (some) overlap there may be an alternative.